# Pandas: Merge dataframe into another dataframe if entries have changed

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas dataframes (Master & Input) with the same Index but a different number of columns, e.g.

Dataframe 1 (Master):

```
ID  | A  | B  | C
101 | .. | .. | ..
102 | .. | .. | ..
103 | .. | .. | ..
```

Dataframe 2 (Input):

```
ID  | A  | B  | C  | E  | F 
101 | .. | .. | .. | .. | ..
102 | .. | XY | YZ | .. | ..
223 | .. | .. | .. | .. | ..
351 | .. | .. | .. | .. | ..
```

I want to merge the Input DF into the Master DF **if new rows have been added** (see ID 223, 351) OR **an item in the Input DF has been updated** (see ID 102).

Additional columns in the Input DF can be ignored.

Goal:

```
ID  | A  | B  | C
101 | .. | .. | ..
102 | .. | XY | YZ
103 | .. | .. | ..
223 | .. | .. | ..
351 | .. | .. | ..
```

Comment: your df2 has values in for ID 102 column E, but this data goes to ID 102 in column C in df1. Is this intended? The colum names are different

Comment: @SandervandenOord Apologies, this was not intended. I corrected the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to update already existing rows and columns.
Then I try to find out what the new rows are that are not yet in your df1 and add those using [pd.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': [101, 102, 103],
     'A': ['..', '..', '..'],
     'B': ['..', '..', '..'],
     'C': ['..', '..', '..'],    
}).set_index('ID')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': [101, 102, 223],
     'A': ['..', '..', '..'],
     'B': ['..', 'XY', '..'],
     'C': ['..', 'ZZ', '..'], 
     'F': ['..', '..', '..'],
}).set_index('ID')

# update existing rows    
df1.update(df2)

# find out which ids are new    
ids_of_new_rows = set(df2.index) - set(df1.index)

# get new rows that should be added to master   
rows_to_add = df2.loc[ids_of_new_rows, df1.columns & df2.columns]

# add new rows to existing master
df_result = pd.concat([df1, rows_to_add])

df_result
```

Comment: Great answer! I would add the conditionals required by the user: `if len(ids_of_new_rows)>0 or not (df1_match == df2_match).values().all(): ...`, where *df1_match* and *df2_match* are the dataframes filtered by the common indexes (`df.loc[set(df1.index) & set(df2.index)`]).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think this is exactly what I need. Unfortunately, I needed to add some manual columns to the master sheet which are not included in the input sheet. Now I always receive an error when trying to get the new rows to be added: "KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index(['Manual Column A', 'Manual Column B'], dtype='object')."

Comment: @maxiw46: i've adjusted the answer to only add columns that are in both df's. In particular i changed the code for: variable rows_to_add

Comment: @SandervandenOord Now I get the following error: "KeyError: "None of [Index(['CR9885', 'CR9890', 'CR9886', 'CR9889', 'CR9887', 'CR9888', 'CR9883',\n       'CR9882', 'CR9884'],\n      dtype='object', name='ID')] are in the [index]". Note that CR123, etc. are my actual IDs.

Comment: hmm, its hard for me to tell what's going on now, since i can't see your real data :(

Comment: I am importing the real data from two Excel sheet using `inputDf = pd.read_excel(inputFileName).set_index("ID")`. However, I already stripped it down to some test data. For me it looks like there are some spaces in the index (see \n in the error message). I double checked already but cannot find any...

Edit: If I change the index to 1, 2, 3, etc., I get the same error `KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], dtype='int64', name='ID')] are in the [index]"`

Comment: Maybe you have to open a new question and give print outs of the results of the different variables, for example, what do you see, when you print out ids_of_new_rows. What do you see when you print out rows_to_add, what does the index of df1 look like and does the index of df2 look like, etc.

Comment: Will do! Nevertheless, thanks a million for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that the columns in `Input` are actually `A,B,C,D`:

```py
useless_col = set(master.columns) ^ set(input.columns)
input = input.drop(columns=useless_col)

master_only = master[~master.id.isin(input.id)]
master_overriden = input[input.id.isin(master.id)]

master_only.append(master_overriden)
```

I tried to find a way using `join` but couldn't find anything as simple as above.

Below is a demo in a shell :

```py
>>> master
    id   A   B   C
0  101  ..  ..  ..
1  102  ..  ..  ..
2  103  ..  ..  ..
>>> input
    id   A   B   C   D
0  101  ..  ..  ..  ..
1  102  ..  XY  YZ  ..
2  223  ..  ..  ..  ..
3  251  ..  ..  ..  ..
>>> 
>>> input = input.drop(columns=set(master.columns) ^ set(input.columns))
>>> 
>>> master_only = master[~master.id.isin(input.id)]
>>> master_overriden = input[input.id.isin(master.id)]
>>> 
>>> master_only.append(master_overriden)
    id   A   B   C
2  103  ..  ..  ..
0  101  ..  ..  ..
1  102  ..  XY  YZ
>>> d = {'A': '..', 'B': '..', 'C': '..'}
>>> master = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 101, **d}, {'id': 102, **d}, {'id': 103, **d}])
>>> input = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 101, **d, 'D': '..'}, {'id': 102, 'A': '..', 'B':'XY', 'C': 'YZ', 'D': '..'}, {'id': 223, **d, 'D': '..'}, {'id':251, **d, 'D': '..'}])
>>> 
>>> master
    id   A   B   C
0  101  ..  ..  ..
1  102  ..  ..  ..
2  103  ..  ..  ..
>>> input
    id   A   B   C   D
0  101  ..  ..  ..  ..
1  102  ..  XY  YZ  ..
2  223  ..  ..  ..  ..
3  251  ..  ..  ..  ..
>>> 
>>> useless_col = set(master.columns) ^ set(input.columns)
>>> useless_col
{'D'}
>>> 
>>> input = input.drop(columns=useless_col)
>>> 
>>> master_only = master[~master.id.isin(input.id)]
>>> master_overriden = input[input.id.isin(master.id)]
>>> 
>>> master_only.append(master_overriden)
    id   A   B   C
2  103  ..  ..  ..
0  101  ..  ..  ..
1  102  ..  XY  YZ
```